# Removing select effect from jQm textbox

Tags: jquery-mobile, jqmobi

I have created two text boxes. A[image] light Gray colour shadow is showing above the textbox. I am unable to remove the effect. I have used jQm CSS file in my project. 
Above is my screen shot.

Comment: post the code or create a plunker and update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shadow effect upon focusing on an input is from the ui-focus css class

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 12px #38c;
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 12px #38c;
box-shadow:0 0 12px #38c
```

If you want to get rid of the shadow, just override the class:

```
.ui-focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

If you don't like the little inset shadow when the text box is not focused, you can override the `ui-shadow-inset` class:

```
.ui-shadow-inset{
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/urhg19qc/2/)**